# Use a Managed Metadata Field as custom property of a WebPart

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, custom-web-part-property, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to add a custom property to a WebPart to select multiple terms from a TermSet in SharePoint 2013.

I have found this article: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
This, however, is tagged for SharePoint 2003.

Then I found this: http://www.dhirajranka.com/?p=420 which is for SharePoint 2010. But it doesn't seem to work either. I can't override the method `GetToolParts()` cause there seems to be none in the WebPart class.

So now I'm back at the start and I don't know where to begin. I don't have any idea left now. Maybe someone can point me into a direction? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: did you try this one: http://www.ashokraja.me/articles/How-to-create-a-custom-property-and-set-a-default-value-in-a-SharePoint-2013-Visual-WebPart

Comment: Is using **TaxonomyWebTaggingControl** an option?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Yes, this is the standard way to add a custom property to a WebPart. However, I guess I need to add a somewhat selfmade control for a Metadata Property.

Comment: @FalakMahmood I don't think it is, cause you can't actually use this control as a WebPart Property, can you?  
If I'm wrong at this, then please let me know.

Comment: You can use `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl` as a custom web part property!

Comment: @FalakMahmood No, you can't. I just tested it and it won't show up in the WebPart Properties. Thats why i said "you were kinda right". There's a litte more to this than just adding a WebPart Property with the `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl` Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question.
You can write your own EditorPart, which will then be displayed in the EditorPanel when you want to change the WebPart Properties.

An example can be found here:
http://geekswithblogs.net/KunaalKapoor/archive/2012/04/26/web-part-to-execute-caml-query---using-managed-metadata.aspx

Thank you everyone!

PS: @FalakMahmood you were kinda right with the TaxonomyWebTaggingControl :)

Comment: You should mark my response as an answer instead of posting on your own! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can incorporate `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl` in your Web Part and bind it with a Tersmset during the run-time:

More info: http://www.vesoftware.in/2012/04/add-taxonomy-field-taxonomywebtaggingco.html

Comment: I don't want to add such a control on my actual WebPart. I want to have a Custom WebPart Property that is configurable via the WebPart Properties dialog.

Comment: As far as I know you can't just add this control as a Custom WebPart Property, or can you?

Comment: You could definitely use that :)